# Skrollr-menu won't function in the original skrollr.js demo

Tags: javascript, html, skrollr

**How can I integrate skrollr-menu into skrollr-master/index.html** (the original skrollr demo) to test it?

So far I've had no luck. I'd love advice on how to do this or a working example.

When I click the link to #easing, nothing happens.

The original skrollr demo can be found here:
https://github.com/Prinzhorn/skrollr/blob/master/index.html

skrollr-menu can be found here:
https://github.com/Prinzhorn/skrollr-menu

Here's what I've tried:

1. I made a link to #easing with this code at the top of the page to make it scroll to the easing section of the demo:

   ```
   <div style="background: red; color: white; z-index: 1000; position: fixed; top: 0;">
   <a href="#easing">Easing....</a>
   </div>
   ```
2. pasted skrollr.menu.js into the src folder and included it below the skrollr.min.js with this code:

   ```
   <script type="text/javascript" src="src/skrollr.menu.js"></script>
   ```
3. I've tried these code variations to get it to work...

3.1 Using the original code from skrollr-menu-master/index.html (removing forceHeight: false, this breaks all scrolling):

```
setTimeout(function() {
    var s = skrollr.init({

    });

    skrollr.menu.init(s);
}, 500);
```

3.2 Including skrollr.menu.init(s); below the original javascript:

```
    var s = skrollr.init({
    edgeStrategy: 'set',
    easing: {
        WTF: Math.random,
        inverted: function(p) {
            return 1-p;
        }
    }
});

skrollr.menu.init(s);
```

Comment: After further testing, I've found adding this parameter:
    data-menu-top="3000"
to the <a> makes it scroll down 3000px. Is there a way to make it scroll to #easing with out calculating the amount of px manually?

Comment: I think this can be done with ["Dynamic constants"](https://github.com/Prinzhorn/skrollr#dynamic-constants) but I am also checking this out. So... I don't know yet but I am about to test it.